# How to Dynamically Control the hintText in a TextFIeld in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have this TextFIeld in Flutter where I want it to start with a prompt like "math" with a slight opacity but then when the user starts typing, whatever they typed stays as the hintText and the opacity is set to one, similar to apples clock app when setting a label for a timer, this is my code:

the TextField:

```
 TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none, // Remove underline
                    hintText: 'Hint', // Add prompt text
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                    ),
                  ),
                  controller: taskEditingController,
                ),
```

and the controllers:

```
   //to control input of New Task TextEditing Controller
    final textEditingControllerProvider =
        Provider.autoDispose((ref) => TextEditingController());

    final taskEditingController = textEditingControllerProvider;
```

if I use the taskEditing controller is just stays empty, whatever the user types should stay on the screen and only be disposed on naviagating exactly like setting the label on the apple timer in their clock app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what exactly you want to achieve (I dont use apple).
But I think the following code might be what you are looking for, you can omit the provider (and maybe even the controller), and change the hintText every time the user completes some input by pressing "enter":

```
TextField(
      onSubmitted: (String text) => setState(() {
        hintText = text;
      }),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none, // Remove underline
        hintText: hintText, // Add prompt text
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 17,
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
        ),
      ),
      controller: TextEditingController(),
    ),
```

and a controller without the provider:

`final taskEditingController = TextEditingController();`

and the hintText attibute with initial hint to be overwritten:

`String hintText = "math";`

Comment: That worked and works with Riverpod too, but how do I now change the opacity to for example 0.9 as soon as the user starts typing and keep it that way when they are done?

Comment: I still do not fully understand your intention. Usually the hint text disappears when the user starts typing. Do you want to display the typed text on top of the hint? Then you probably need a Stack of two Textfields (or of one Textfield for the input and one Text for the hint).
If you only want to specify different opacities for the text and for the hint, you just need to add a style to the TextField outside the decoration:

```TextField(
   //...
   controller: ...,
   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9)),
)```

Comment: yes so the way it works is the hint text is shown as soon as you open the page and then when you start typing, whatever you typed becomes the hintText and now its both your input and the hintText, so I need a way to change that opacity number when the user is finished typing